# How to compress numpy array for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, numpy

I want to save a numpy 2d array as part of a mongodb document, but the resulting size of the document is 71 MB, well above the 16 MB limit. The numpy array is sparse. Any suggestions on how to compress the numpy 2d array, or save it in a more memory efficient manner? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The idea of stackoverflow is that people do something and ask for clarification. Not crowdsourcing their work for other people.

Comment: I'm doing a project and asking for clarification on a step I'm stuck on. I didn't think it was necessary to display any code to answer this question.

Comment: It is hard to add anything else except of http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/. You have not done even simple googling. Sparce matrices are not new to a math world and I expected that you will at least google these keywords and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is sparse, you can easily convert a numpy array to a supported scipy sparse format and back:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

You can then save it using the Matrix Market format

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmwrite.html

Or you can save the numpy array directly in a compressed form using `savez_compressed`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html

I'm not familiar with MongoDB though, so I'm not sure what file formats or objects are supported.